# Animating GIFs on a web page - Any way to restart them?

Tags: javascript, preloader, animated-gif

I have the following scenario:
A specific section of my website has an 800x600 section that has a background image and multiple other images overlaid on top (using position:absolute). When one of these images is clicked, the image is swapped with an animated GIF to make it appear as if something happened. These animations usually run once (not looped).
After a pre-defined "animation duration", the animated GIF is swapped back to the original static image.

That all works fine, except I have no way of knowing how long it's going to take the animated GIF to download, which introduces the possibility of clicking on the item and nothing appearing to happen for the full animation duration.
The solution to this problem is simple enough: Pre-load the images. And, indeed, I am using [PxLoader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/) to pre-load all the images I need.

However this introduces a new problem in some browsers: The animation plays once and never plays again. In Firefox it seems to work properly (you click, animation plays. You click again, animation plays again). However in IE, it doesn't seem to work (you click, it shows the last frame of the animation).

I've set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem: [jsfiddle.net/xJveS/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/xJveS/4/)

What are my options? How can I "reset" the GIF to play again when I show it the next time?

**Update**

I ended up building my own (very basic) pre-loader class to replace PxLoader for the animated GIFs, and it does not suffer the issue. The GIFs replay fine when I click on them. Which means my whole problem is something specific to PxLoader. For now my problem is "solved" by using my own loader, but there is still an issue with PxLoader that needs resolving.

Comment: maybe you could try resetting the src attribute of the image.  If it's preloaded it won't have to d/l again and resetting it might recycle the gif animation.

Comment: you could always make your gif a sprite instead and set it as a div background image and in the sprite have the frames directly under each other then just use jquery to adjust the background images y-axis. this way you can control the speed of the animation, do callbacks etc...

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson Isn't that what I'm doing in the jsfiddle? Or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: @codewombat, that's a pretty good idea, but the system is to be used by clients who won't understand how to build a sprite sheet (but do understand how to build animated GIFs, go figure). I'm toying with the idea of doing some server-side processing to convert the animation into a spritesheet myself, but would rather not have to.

Comment: @death_au I don't know what you're doing with your jsfiddle...I get a 404 when I click your link.

Comment: Do you have Photoshop? as that has a function in the save for web dialog to loop a gif forever.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson Sorry about that. Not sure why that happened. Link is fixed now.

Comment: @ThomasBrasington - The problem is that I won't be specifying the GIFs, the clients will. And besides, there are a lot of instances where a non-looped GIF makes much more sense. I wouldn't really want the GIF to be in the middle of its loop when the image is clicked and halfway through the next loop when the animation ends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load the GIF in a hidden div and then when you need it add the  tag for it in your target location. The browser will have cached it from the first request so it should show right away.

Comment: I figured that's what PxLoader is for. It should be preloading my images so the image shows right away.
However, I tried it anyway and it works fine in IE. Then I tried using the javascript Image object to do the same thing (without putting it in a hidden div) and it also worked in IE. Then I realized I'd built my own basic preloader which works fine, so it must be something specific to PxLoader that's causing this issue... In short: I got it working thanks to your answer, but your answer is not THE answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to restart a .gif from JavaScript.

You should be able to reload it by setting the src to the same thing with a query string on the end. (sorry, I'm using jQuery to be efficient with my time, lol)

```
$('#myImg').attr('src', $('#myImg').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).valueOf());
```

The downside is it will force the gif to download again before it restarts. So the next thing you'd want to do is implement some sort of preloader to preload the replacement gif from the new src.

```
var rplImg;
function preloadReplacement() {
 rplImg = new Image();
 var d = new Date();
 rplImg.src = "some.gif?" + d.valueOf();
}
$(function()  {
  preloadReplacement();
  $('#myImg').click(function(){ 
      $(this).attr('src', rplImg.src);
      preloadReplacement();
  });
});
```

**This is untested**, but it's the basic idea.